# navigate to another url in MVC partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have one partial view call **_mainMenu.cshtml**

```
<div id="main-menu">
<div class="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="six" style="height:100%;width: 500px;">
        <li ><a href="#" style="font-weight:500; font-size:medium; text-align:center">ABC</a></li>&nbsp;
        <li ><a href="#" style="font-weight:500; font-size:medium; text-align:center">abc</a></li>&nbsp;
        <li ><a href="#" style="font-weight:500; font-size:medium; text-align:center">abc</a></li>&nbsp;
        <li ><a href="#" style="font-weight:500; font-size:medium; text-align:center">abc</a></li>&nbsp;
        <li><a href="#" style="font-weight:500; font-size:medium; text-align:center">abc</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now i want to Navigate each link to different different .cshtml pages.. so how should i do this..or what should i write in Controller.

Comment: Have you googled? Have you run through the first tutorials of ASP.NET MVC? That's a really basic question. Please,go and make some of the asp.net tutorials: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Following one

```
    <a href="@Url.Action("actionmethod", "controller")">Home</a>
```

Comment: Got the solution....

Comment: ya i got the solution